# Get a list of all videos from the device storage

Tags: ios, swift, file-handling

I am working on Xcode 14. I need help fetching details like URL, duration, thumbnail, and title of all the videos present on the device in iOS. I tried all the approaches available out there. None seem to work. I have modified the info area for requesting video and photo access. Yes, the app has necessary permissions. Somehow, trying to fetch all the photos works. Only the videos part is not working. Here are the two popular solutions that I tried.

```
func showVideosOnDevice() {
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d ", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue )
    
    let allVideo = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions)
    allVideo.enumerateObjects { (asset, index, bool) in
        // videoAssets.append(asset)
        let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()
        imageManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil, resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) in
            if asset != nil {
                let avasset = asset as! AVURLAsset
                let urlVideo = avasset.url
                print(urlVideo)
            }
        })
    }
}


func fetchVideoURLs() -> [URL] {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    var videoURLs: [URL] = []
    
    do {
        let videoFiles = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
        for file in videoFiles {
            if file.pathExtension.lowercased() == "mov" || file.pathExtension.lowercased() == "mkv" || file.pathExtension.lowercased() == "mp4" {
                videoURLs.append(file)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error while fetching video URLs: \(error)")
    }
    
    return videoURLs
}
```

BTW, all of my videos are in the Downloads folder, as I downloaded them from Safari. That shouldn't be the root cause of this issue I guess.

Comment: Just at first glance, you say your videos are in the downloads folder but you pass the documents directory in `fetchVideoURLs`. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @gmdev yes I was just trying different things, so I mentioned document. And btw, I solved this issue. We have to "save" whatever we download to apple photos in order for the apps to access them.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Downloading something is not enought. We need to save it. One way to save it is.

- Select all the videos from your downloads folder.
- Click on share.
- Click on save.

Done!! Now all the videos are in apple photos and the apps that have access to photos will be able to access the videos.